# Get Django model's table name directly from database

Tags: django, django-models

I need to retrive table name and model's contenttype id for all model of a specific app. I can use this code to get a model's table name, but *not* its contenttype id:

```
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models
app = get_app("my_app_name")
for model in get_models(app, include_auto_created=True):
    print model._meta.db_table
```

However I need to directly get this information from database. Something like:

```
Select id, model from django_content_type where app_label='my_app_name'
```

In this case, I get id but not table name. Where to get table name in 2nd case?

Comment: "I need to directly get this information from database" ... Why?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am using hard coded fixtures to directly populate tons of data in database, bypassing all of django. I need this info there, where all I have is raw database..

Comment: I'm afraid the table name of a model is stored in code, instead of in `django_content_type` if db_table is specified as non-default value.

Comment: @okm ok then please let me know how to get django_content_type id for model in 1st case. And also how to spoof django environment variable to allow this code to execute in my fixtures..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the pk of the contenttype of a model

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model).pk
```

To [run standalone Django script](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/), refs [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+standalone) or simply (which normally works)

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='project.settings' python script.py
```

Comment: +1 and thanks and okm. I appended this in my script: `sys.path.append('../../projects')
sys.path.append('../../apps')
sys.path.append('../../external_apps/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'core.settings'`